# ASP.NET Web API post method in controller not passing values to Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, postman, http-post

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddNewUser([FromBody]  dynamic user)
{
    try
    {
        dynamic new_user = await new Models.Users().addUser(user.username,user.password,user.email,user.firstName,user.lastName);

        if (new_user.GetType() == typeof(User))
        {
            return Ok(Helper.SuccessResponse(new_user));
        }
        else 
            throw new Exception(new_user.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        return BadRequest(Helper.ErrorResponse(ex.Message));
    }
}
```

This is my controller method after getting values from Body it should pass values to the `addUser()` method in the models and save data into the database but it neither moves to the model nor save the values in the database instead it throws a 500 internal server error exception.

My model class is as below:

```
public class Users
{
        public async Task<dynamic> addUser(string username, string password, string email, string first_name, string last_name)
        {
            try
            {
                hospiceEntities db = new hospiceEntities();
                
                User user = new User();
                Resource detail = new Resource();

                Guid user_id = new Guid();

                user.Id = user_id;
                user.UserName = username;
                user.PasswordHash = Helper.HashPassword(password);
                user.Discriminator = "Discriminator";
                user.ApplicationId = new Guid();
                user.LoweredUserName = username.ToLower();
                user.IsAnonymous = false;
                user.Email = email;
                user.IsApproved = false;
                user.IsLockedOut = false;
                user.CreateDate = new DateTime();
                user.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount = 0;
                user.IsTempPassword = false;
                user.LockoutCount = 0;
                user.AccessFailedCount = 0;
                user.LockoutEnabled = false;

                detail.ResourceId = new Guid();
                detail.ResourceNo = 1;
                detail.UserId = user_id;
                detail.ClientId = 1;
                detail.FirstName = first_name;
                detail.LastName = last_name;

                db.Users.Add(user);
                db.Resources.Add(detail);

                await db.SaveChangesAsync();

                return user;
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                return ex; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks

**Resource Class:**

```
 public partial class Resource
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Resource()
        {
            this.Activities = new HashSet<Activity>();
            this.Facilities = new HashSet<Facility>();
            this.IntakeLogs = new HashSet<IntakeLog>();
            this.NoteComments = new HashSet<NoteComment>();
            this.NoteMentions = new HashSet<NoteMention>();
            this.Patients = new HashSet<Patient>();
            this.ResourceInOffices = new HashSet<ResourceInOffice>();
            this.NoteNotifications = new HashSet<NoteNotification>();
            this.ReferralSources = new HashSet<ReferralSource>();
        }
    
        public int ResourceNo { get; set; }
        public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> BirthDate { get; set; }
        public string SSN { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }
        public string Ethnicity { get; set; }
        public string WorkerTypeCode { get; set; }
        public string LicenseNo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> JobTitleId { get; set; }
        public string CredentialCode1 { get; set; }
        public string CredentialCode2 { get; set; }
        public string CredentialCode3 { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string employmentType { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> ContactInfoId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> InternSupervisorUserId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> TerminationDate { get; set; }
        public string RegularVisitCompensationType { get; set; }
        public string OnCallVisitCompensationType { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> OvertimeAllowed { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> FFVVisitHourMaximum { get; set; }
        public string oncallemploymenttype { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> PTOAnniversaryStartDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> PTOStartingYearOfService { get; set; }
        public string PTANNumber { get; set; }
        public string NPINumber { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public string DEANumber { get; set; }
        public System.Guid ResourceId { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Facility> Facilities { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<IntakeLog> IntakeLogs { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<NoteComment> NoteComments { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<NoteMention> NoteMentions { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
        public virtual ResourceInJobTitle ResourceInJobTitle { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ResourceInOffice> ResourceInOffices { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<NoteNotification> NoteNotifications { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ReferralSource> ReferralSources { get; set; }
    }
```

**Users Class:**

```
public partial class User
    {
       

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public User()
        {
            this.ChatMessages = new HashSet<ChatMessage>();
            this.Notes = new HashSet<Note>();
            this.ReferralSourceNotes = new HashSet<ReferralSourceNote>();
            this.Resources = new HashSet<Resource>();
            this.Tasks = new HashSet<Task>();
            this.Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
            this.ChatRooms = new HashSet<ChatRoom>();
        }
    
        public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
        public string Discriminator { get; set; }
        public System.Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public string LegacyPasswordHash { get; set; }
        public string LoweredUserName { get; set; }
        public string MobileAlias { get; set; }
        public bool IsAnonymous { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> LastActivityDate { get; set; }
        public string MobilePIN { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string LoweredEmail { get; set; }
        public string PasswordQuestion { get; set; }
        public string PasswordAnswer { get; set; }
        public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
        public bool IsLockedOut { get; set; }
        public System.DateTimeOffset CreateDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> LastLoginDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> LastPasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> LastLockoutDate { get; set; }
        public int FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public bool IsTempPassword { get; set; }
        public int LockoutCount { get; set; }
        public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }
        public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ChatMessage> ChatMessages { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ReferralSourceNote> ReferralSourceNotes { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Resource> Resources { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ChatRoom> ChatRooms { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You have to post User and  Resource class too

Comment: can you explain what u mean to say ?

Comment: You are mentioning User and Resource classes in your code. Can you include them in your answer as they are in your db context pls?

Comment: posted please check now

Answer (score 0):

for the start remove dynamic from your code. I can not see any sense in it if you are using User class. Why don't use it explicetly. And you have to create a view model for your view if you don't want to use the whole User class

```
public class UserViewModel
{
public string username {get; set;}
public string password {get; set;}
public string email { get; set; }
public string first_name { get; set; }
public string last_name {get;set;}
}
```

after this fix the action

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddNewUser([FromBody]  UserViewModel model)
{
 try
    {
       var new_user = await new Models.Users().addUser(model);
     if (new_user.GetType() == typeof(User))
        {
            return Ok(Helper.SuccessResponse(new_user));
        }
        else 
            throw new Exception(new_user.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        return BadRequest(Helper.ErrorResponse(ex.Message));
    }
}
.....
```

and  remove  db.Resources.Add(detail) from repository

```
public async Task<User> addUser(UserViewModel model)
{
.....
 detail.ResourceId = new Guid();
detail.ResourceNo = 1;
 detail.ClientId = 1;
   detail.FirstName = model.first_name;
  detail.LastName = model.last_name;

  user.Resources= new List<Resource>();
  user.Resources.Add(detail);

 db.Users.Add(user);
 await db.SaveChangesAsync();
 return user;

}
```

Comment: let me try this

Comment: can we use viewmodels in web apis ?

Comment: @Sadia yes, since you are using  [frombody]

Comment: how to modify this line in post method?   dynamic new_user = await new Models.Users().addUser(user.username, user.password, user.email, user.first_name, user.last_name);

Comment: @Sadia see my answer

Comment: i have made the changes but inside post method how to pass the entered data from model and get stored in db